# Review lasting 6 weeks

Tags: publications

The status of my paper which is in review since 3/02 is "A review is overdue. Two of 4 Assigned reviews are completed". I read in the journal site that review generally takes 1 month and the minimum number of reviews to make a decision by the editor is 2. The number of reviews is 2 since 1 March and the editor didn't make any decision? What should I do?

Comment: Write to the editor and ask kindly what the current status is.

Answer (score 6):

It's not true that just because your manuscript already has two reviews that the editor will make a decision. For example, maybe the two reviews disagree with each other, or one of the two reviews is poor and the editor is waiting for the third review as a tiebreaker. The third review is ten days overdue which is not a good sign, but you can't tell from the outside. For example, maybe the reviewer had emailed the editor saying the review will be late, and the editor is (sensibly) waiting as a result.

As for "what should I do", the answer is always the same. If you're concerned/impatient, write to the editor and ask what the status is. Otherwise just wait. The review process for your manuscript doesn't seem that long to me, so I would wait, but it's up to you.

Comment: `The third review is ten days overdue which is not a good sign` Ha! In my experience with journals (in computer science), lateness is measured in months, not days.

Comment: To echo @Thomas 's comment, this varies a lot by field. Some fields this is a big deal. Others this is routine.

Comment: @Thomas true, but being late in the first place is not a good sign =)

Comment: I've once had to wait 14 months and it was accepted with minor corrections